# How to determine if word in string is a double word?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function that takes a file as a string, and returns True if the file has duplicate words and False otherwise.

So far I have:

```
def double(filename):
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    res = False
    l = infile.split()
    infile.close()

    for line in l:
        #if line is in l twice
        res = True
    return res
```

if my file contains:
"there is is a same word"

I should get True

if my file contains:
"there is not a same word"

I should get False

How do I determine if there is a duplicate of a word in the string

P.S. the duplicate word does not have to come right after the other
i.e In "there is a same word in the sentence over there" should return True because "there" is also a duplicate.

Comment: On a side note: there is a provable lower-bound complexity of `O(nlogn)` for this problem, i.e. you could simply take all words, sort them and check for consecutive duplicates and you'd have an optimal worst-case solution. Although hashing will have `O(n)` *average* performances in most situations.

Comment: @Bakuriu It is profoundly misleading to focus on the worst case performance of hash tables.  While it is *possible* for them to have O(n) collision pile-ups, it is almost never occurs in practice (and the risk can be reduced to an infintesimal by modest hash randomization).  Practically, hash tables do *much* better than sorting algorithms.  The one-line solution using *Counter* gets the job done in O(n) time for all but the most deliberately adversarial datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a set to detect duplicates:

```
def double(filename):
    seen = set()
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for line in l:
            for word in line.split():
                if word in seen:
                     return True
                seen.add(word)
    return False
```

You could shorten that to:

```
def double(filename):
    seen = set()
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        return any(word in seen or seen.add(word) for line in l for word in line.split())
```

Both versions exit early; as soon as a duplicate word is found, the function returns `True`; it does have to read the whole file to determine there are no duplicates and return `False`.

Answer (score 4):

The [*str.split()*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method doesn't work well for splitting words in natural English text because of apostrophes and punctuation.  You usually need the power of [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) for this:

```
>>> text = """I ain't gonna say ain't, because it isn't
in the dictionary. But my dictionary has it anyways."""

>>> text.lower().split()
['i', "ain't", 'gonna', 'say', "ain't,", 'because', 'it', "isn't", 'in', 'the',
 'dictionary.', 'but', 'my', 'dictionary', 'has', 'it', 'anyways.']

>>> re.findall(r"[a-z']+", text.lower())
['i', "ain't", 'gonna', 'say', "ain't", 'because', 'it', "isn't", 'in', 'the',
 'dictionary', 'but', 'my', 'dictionary', 'has', 'it', 'anyways']
```

To find whether there are any duplicate words, you can use [set operations](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
>>> len(words) != len(set(words))
True
```

To list out the duplicate words, use the multiset operations in [*collections.Counter*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> sorted(Counter(words) - Counter(set(words)))
["ain't", 'dictionary', 'it']
```

Comment: Clear and beautiful. After having watched a couple of your PyCon videos, now I am going through all of your answers here and my code gets better everyday. Just wanted to say thank you :) ps. If I, one day, get a millionaire thanks to python, I'm gonna send you some booze :)

Answer (score 3):

```
def has_duplicates(filename):
    seen = set()
    for line in open(filename):
        for word in line.split():
            if word in seen:
                return True
            seen.add(word)
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = set()
for line in l:
  if (line in a):
    return True
  a.add(line)
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Another general approach to detecting duplicate words, involving `collections.Counter`

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
with open('test_file.txt') as f:
    x = Counter(chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in f))
    for (key, value) in x.iteritems():
            if value > 1:
                    print key
```

Comment: This needs to read the entire file, even if there is a duplicate word in the very first line.

Comment: @timpietzcker,  you are right. This is more of a general word-counting approach than strictly an answer to the OP's True/False requirement.